# Nvim for typescript - cannot see full error message

Tags: neovim

I am using `mhartington/nvim-typescript` and when I am getting an error I can see it like:

[image]

Is there any way to automatically increase high so the message will be fully displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that `nvim-typescript` includes a way to adjust this out of the box, but you might consider using a higher value for `cmdheight`:

```
set cmdheight=2
```

or alternatively binding a key to temporarily increase and decrease its height. You could also check the location list and quickfix windows to see if the error content is there. Use `:lopen`, `:lclose` and `:copen`, `:cclose` respectively.